# Can I use a conversion constructor to handle inheritance chain in template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Suppose I have `class D` which inherits from `class B`. and I have a template class `template <class T> C`. And then I have a function signature `void foo(C<B> c);`. In order to make that work with an instance of `C` templated with a derived class from `B` do I need to provide a conversion constructor? Something like `template <class DERIVED> C(const C<DERIVED>& c) {}`? Will this be enough for anything else that happens in `C` since any `D` is a `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C<D>` and `C<B>` will not be related types at all, so yes, you'd have to provide a conversion that allows a `C<B>` to be constructed from a `C<D>`.

This probably will not make the types perfectly compatible. For example a function `void foo(C<B> &c)` will not be able to use that conversion.

Whether these unrelated types can be made compatible enough for your uses depends on how you define the types and what you need from them in terms of compatibility.

---

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};

template<typename T>
struct C {};

int main() {
    C<B> c = C<D>();
}
```

---

```
test1.cpp:9:10: error: no viable conversion from 'C<struct D>' to 'C<struct B>'
    C<B> c = C<D>();
         ^   ~~~~~~
```

Consider this example for why there should not be any relationship between different specializations of a template:

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};

template<typename T> struct C;

template<> struct C<B> { int i; }; // different specializations
template<> struct C<D> { double a, b, c; }; // can have different definitions
```

Converting between types related by inheritance works because a derived type always has a sub-object of the base type. Even so, types that use inheritance must be carefully designed in order to work well.

---

User defined conversions operate via non-explicit constructors and type operators:

```
struct T {};

struct S {
    S() {}
    S(T const &) {}
    operator T () { return T(); }
};

void foo(T t) {}
void bar(S s) {}

int main() {
    foo(S()); // uses S::operator T ()
    bar(T()); // uses S::S(T const &)
}
```

You can read more in the standard *12.3.2 Conversion functions [class.conv.fct]* and about how they are used in overload resolution *13.3 Overload resolution [over.match]*.

Comment: Right, but in the case of `C<B>` to `C<D>` that should "work out of the box" I presume. Are there other types of conversion operators besides construction? I'm interested in learning more about this whether from the standard itself or anywhere online.

Comment: No, converting between `C<D>` and `C<B>` does not work 'out of the box.' They are not related types. The fact that the type parameters, D and B, are related by inheritance conveys nothing to the template specializations `C<D>` and `C<B>`.

Comment: Oh yes, I guess that's not what I meant with work out of the box but yea thanks! Great answer and thanks for the references.